# Creating a Func<object[], object> Delegate from MethodInfo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, delegates, mono

After much research and searching on SO; I've failed to find an answer that encompasses my specific situation. I wish to add modding capabilities to my project; currently I use a 3rd-party C# API which can convert scripts written in a particular interpreted language (specifically the functions in these scripts) into C# delegates.

Is there a way to wrap all of the delegates I get from the 3rd party API, into the a generic Func Delegate? My thoughts (in code) follow...

```
//The goal signature for all 'imported' delegates
public delegate object GenericSignature(object[] args);

//A fictional example...
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        GenericSignature desiredFunc = GenerateFromArbitraryMethod(
               Program.FictionalArbitraryMethod);
        object retVal = desiredFunc(1, new object(), "If only this worked");
    }

    public static FictionalArbitraryMethod(int num, object stuff, string name) 
    { 
        //code from mod author would be here 
    }
}

//Attempt #1
//If my understanding about Delegate.CreateDelegate() is correct, 
//this will not work... 
public GenericSignature GenerateFromArbitraryMethod(Delegate d) {
    MethodInfo mInfo = d.Method;
    return (GenericSignature) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(GenericSignature), mInfo);
}

//Attempt #2
//seems a bit... better?; I can do some validation, but how do I actually call the 
//function represented by MethodInfo since it's signature is arbitrary?
public GenericSignature GenerateFromArbitraryMethod(Delegate d) {
    MethodInfo mInfo = d.Method;

    return delegate(object[] args) {

        ParameterInfo[] pInfo = mInfo.GetParameters();
        if(args.length != pInfo.length) {
             throw new Exception("Argument count does not match");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
             if(pInfo[i].ParameterType != args[i].GetType()) {
                 throw new Exception("Incorrect Type for argument");
             } 
        }

        //At a loss of how to do the following; fake psuedo-code follows
        /*
        Foreach(object currentArg in arg) {
           d.AppendArgAndCast(currentArg); 
        }
        return d.Call();

        or...

        return d(EachOrUnpackAndCast(args));
        */

    };
}
```

Apologies if there are any errors in the syntax; I'm mainly trying to get across the concept of what I'm trying to achieve. Some additional notes:

1. Based on info from [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/to-linq-or-not-to-linq.223887/); Unity supports .NET 3.5 features; so the solution I would use can leverage up to .NET 3.5.
2. It is ok if any suggested solution is 'slow/heavy' due to heavy use of reflection; as long as I can generate a delegate, which I can cache and just call many, many times (to amortize the initial delegate creation cost)
3. Delegate.DynamicInvoke() does not meet my project's performance requirements. My understanding is reflection APIs are used per DynamicInvoke() call. Using reflection one time to create the faster delegate is preferable.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Given a delegate instance and an array of arguments to pass, why can't you just call `Delegate.DynamicInvoke()` and pass the array to that? Please try to make your code example clearer, especially regarding what specifically you're having trouble with and what you want to work. Comments like "probably will not work" aren't helpful; either it works or it doesn't. Don't ask us to figure out whether it'll work or not; try it yourself and then if it doesn't explain specifically what's not working and what you need help with.

Comment: Delegate.DynamicInvoke() is too slow for my usecase; Ill update the question with this information; I had forgotten to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your own bytecode to cast each argument from `object` to the correct type.

If you can upgrade from .Net 2, `Expression` makes this very easy.
If not, you'll need to use ILGenerator, or a wrapper such as Sigil.

Comment: I've updated my question with more specific information; the project is actually a Unity project. I believe the project settings do target .net 2.0 and yet Intellisense does find "System.Linq.Expressions" for import; does this mean there is hope?

Comment: @AMemberofDollars I don't know if expressions was ported to the version of Mono uses or not. Intelisense all depends on what .net version the .csproj is targeting. Do you have the Unity tools for Visual Studio installed? What version does your project properties say you are targeting (If you can't open project properties that means you do have the tools installed and unity generated the .csproj file so you don't need to worry about it being the wrong version).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Hi Scott; Yes I do have 'Unity Tools for VS' installed and Im unable to view the project properties. Everything is pointing to the fact that LINQ Expressions should be supported.

Comment: @AMemberofDollars Then try it and see what happens.

Comment: @SLaks I'll see if I can figure out how to use Expressions to solve my issue; if I'm able to come up with something, Ill mark this question as complete.